Jenkins doesn't recognize a local repository
I use a local Jenkins service on Ubuntu. I have created a local git repository with a Jenkinsfile:
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

The path to the local git repository looks this way: /home/my_user/projects/my_repo
Next I have created a mulitbranch pipeline job. I haved added Source/Git with the following path:
file:///home/my_user/projects/my_repo.git

and Credentials "None"
in the job configuration. Jenkins return the following message:
stderr: fatal: '/home/my_user/projects/my_repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

How to fix that ?

To use a local repository as the "remote" you should pass the actual path, e.g. simply file:///home/my_user/projects/my_repo. The .git syntax is for resources provided by github, etc.

Now I get the following message:
To add an exception for this directory, call: git config --global --add safe.directory /home/my_user/my_repo/.git
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
``` What does it mean ? Should I execute the above instructions ?

Generally try creating repos and using repos as the same user. And the command is safe to execute in your case.

I have created a Jenkins user with the same name as my linux user but I still get the above message. It looks like the Jenkins execute the git command as other user. How to verify/change that ?

Even after executing the following command: git config --global --add safe.directory /home/my_user/projects/my_repo/.git I get the same message from the Jenkins. git config --list shows appropriate safe.directory

Is the Jenkins user allowed to access and change items on the (base) directory given? (The linux commands "chown" and "chmod" may be of interest, please read carefully and in full; for more info a search of "linux file permissions" might give you more info)

sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins my_repo fixed it.

Glad you could solve the git user problem as well. That would have been worth its own question, I'm sure it comes up regularly (and not only for Jenkins users).
